# Why is the first element of my array formatted differently than the rest when reading them into cells?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, date, format

I was hoping you could help me with this issue: I have an **array of strings** that I'm using it to iteratively populate a column of cells with each of its values respectively. It parts from the current Date retrieved as a system's variable and tracks backwards until a condition is met.

The problem I'm having is that the **1<sup>st</sup> element** of my array **is being formatted differently than the rest** in its output cell despite being in the same loop and destination column.

The wrong output is:

- **13/01/2023**
- 01/12/2023
- 01/11/2023
- 01/10/2023
- 01/09/2023
- 01/08/2023
- 01/07/2023

When what I was expecting instead  is:

- 01/13/2023
- 01/12/2023
- 01/11/2023
- 01/10/2023
- 01/09/2023
- 01/08/2023
- 01/07/2023

My code is as follows:

```
Dim element() As Variant
Dim Tday, counter, adjustment As Integer

Tday = 7
i = Tday

'Here i use "adjustment" to offset days (e.g. when its monday but i need to start Friday and backwards.)
'For simplicity's sake I'm hardcoding it at 3 for this question.
adjustment = 3


While i <> 0

        counter = Tday - i
        'I'm Dynamically Allocate array's size as needed
        ReDim Preserve element(counter)
        element(counter) = Format(Date - (counter + adjustment), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        i = i - 1

Wend

'SO Far the array is correctly formatted  but...

'HERE IS THE PROBLEM: Reading the values of the array and placing them into cells returns an unexpected format in its first iteration:

For i = LBound(element) To UBound(element)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & 1 + i) = Format(element(i), "mm/dd/yyyy")
Next i
```

As you'll notice I'm implementing the format function since I ultimately need the cells to be text and in the indicated date format **mm/dd/yyyy** for these will be the criteria for an advanced filter which retrieves the records with such dates in my source data table.

I kindly thank your input in advance.

1. I've already attempted to change the type of the **elements** array into Date, however this causes the unexpected behavior (dd/mm/yyyy) directly in the array itself instead of further down the code.
2. The format function appears a second time because it helped me maintain the desired format when assigning cells the values contained in the array. With the sole exception of the first value which won't assume the indicated date formatting.

Comment: What is your default date format e.g. `mm/dd/yyyy`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, `dd.mm.yyyy`, or something else?

Comment: @VBasic2008 of course! It is: dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the cells as text if that's what you want.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub macro1()

    Dim arDates() As String, i As Long
    Dim NoOfDays As Long, startday As Long
    
    NoOfDays = 7
    startday = 3 ' start wednesday
    
    ReDim arDates(1 To NoOfDays, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To NoOfDays
        arDates(i, 1) = Format(Date + 1 - startday - i, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Next
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(NoOfDays)
       .NumberFormat = "@"
       .Value2 = arDates
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Flirting with dates again. If your default format is `dd/mm/yyyy`, how do you get real (usable) dates to display in `mm/dd/yyyy` format?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! **It does work** but I'm afraid that casting the values as text caused the advanced filter further down my code to malfunction for it no longer recognizes the values as valid criteria (for an unknown reason) and then returns an empty table. Although I'll mark this as the actual answer for you responded what I pointed to here thanks!

Comment: @VBasic2008 The deal with my particular situation is that I'm using these values as the **criteria for an advanced filter** if I can manage to keep them just as they appear in the array of my initial code the filter works. But it bugs me that it is just in the first iteration that the value placed in the cells is formatted but the rest aren't and the array's format is respected which causes me to lose a whole day's worth of data. I hope this better clarifies the trouble I'm having.

Comment: @VBasic2008 If you declare the array as a string and format the cells as text then I guessed excel won't treat as date.

Comment: @LuisFernando I have just asked CDP1802 a question that possibly could help in your quest but has little to do with the way you are trying to achieve this. On the other hand, I asked you a question in your comments and you didn't answer. Could you, so I could continue my investigation in another direction? Do it in your comments section.

Comment: @LuisF If you want to use the array in a filter you may have to transpose it because it is 2D not 1D. `ar= Application.Transpose(arDates)` will give you a 1D array

Comment: I asked you a different question. I want to display the dates in the cells and format them `mm/dd/yyyy` and be able in B1 to use `=Day(A1)` and it would return 13.

Answer (score 1):

Your program change the format of the array, not the cell so you need to change the format of the cell:

To have cells as text

```
For i = LBound(element) To UBound(element)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & 1 + i).NumberFormat = "@"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & 1 + i).value = Format(element(i), "mm/dd/yyyy")
Next i
```

Comment: Hi! I really appreciate your response. This appears to work for the first element of the array, however it now inverts problem changing the other 6 into the wrong format :( Might I add that these are actually text data types, maybe another way to see the problem I'm experiening is that the first element is being formatted as a Date when I want to preserve it 'as is' in the array.

Comment: @LuisFernando. what do you want to have in the cells? a date or a string text with a format?

Comment: I want the cells to be String text with the format **"mm/dd/yyyy"** and not strictly a usable date. This format is how it already exists in the array provided in my initial code prior to the for loop. The desired format holds throughout _with the sole exception_ of the first iteration in the for loop where it assigns its corresponding cell the format "dd/mm/yyyy" for a reason I don't understand since the rest of the values DO respect the format they have in the array and are under this same loop,

Comment: Edited answer should work, take notice of the .value

Comment: Thanks a bunch! As with the other thread in this post it did solve the problem, albeit with some exceptions which continue to frustrate me. I appreciate your time and input!